# mapview fragment inside scrollivew flickering

Tags: google-maps, android-fragments, scrollview, android-scrollview, supportmapfragment

In the Main layout, I have used MapFragment inside a scrollview. Everything seems perfect at first, but there is an issue with the Map when I start scrolling inside scrollview, map flickers and displays background activity layout and below 4.4 it displays home screen layout.see below is XML code.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:id="@+id/map"
                        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set this in your manifest file inside  tag
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Comment: Not Working properly